# Putting 3d dice into LaTeX

Tags: symbols

In the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) by Scott Pakin, there are some dice on page 203.  On page 186 there are some instructions about what will be needed to implement the dice.  But I don't really understand them.

Would it be possible to see a simple example showing `\Pisymbol{dice3d}{107}`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple small example (with `102` instead of `107` :-) is

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{dice3d}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dice3d}{m}{n}{<-> s*[4] dice3d}{}

\begin{document}

\Pisymbol{dice3d}{102}

{\usefont{U}{dice3d}{m}{n}6a 2b 3d}

\end{document}
```

Note you need to use `dice3d` despite the `dice` heading in the symbol list.  The above includes the symbol list's advice about scaling up the pictures via the `\DeclareFontShape` where the `s*[4]` means four times (`*[4]`) the requested size, without any warning messages (`s`).

In the `\usefont` example, a straight number such as `4` produces a 2d dice with that number on it, `4a`, `4b`, `4c` and `4d` produces the four different 3d die with the number `4` on the top face, with the front face increasing with the letter.