# RPG Dice Symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for suggestions on a symbol package to add dice shapes to my game rulebook project. So far, even with research, I couldn't find much.

I'm looking for outlines of D4, D6, D8, D10, D12, D20 dice. A bonus would be to have 3D versions of the same, with and without numbers. Simply put, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426746/putting-3d-dice-into-latex), or stix-like packaged, but with all common RPG dice shapes.

I'm open to best alternatives.

Comment: Possible place to start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88770/125871

Comment: For d6 I use 'epsdice' https://ctan.org/pkg/epsdice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made a simple package for this: [ttfdice](https://github.com/glatavento/ttfdice).

[image: Usage]

Comment: +1: Out of curiosity, did you write the package code by hand or did you use some kind of code generator?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Mostly by hand (with many Ctrl-C&Vs), hard coded part by Github Copilot.

Answer (score 6):

There are several dice fonts around, I picked an open source one from https://dicefont.com/
(random find from search, not one I knew) This has several dice glyphs in a truetype font:

[image]

A simple use in lualatex or xelatex would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\dice{dicefont.ttf}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{1cm}{1.1cm}\selectfont

{\dice ^^^^f101}

{\dice ^^^^f111 ^^^^f116}

{\dice 
^^^^f120  ^^^^f125}
\end{document}
```